# Android Calling getview

Tags: android, view, textview, listadapter, method-call

I have a question about the method getview in android.
My getview method(in the class `QuestionsListAdapter`):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    QuestionView qv;
    if (convertView == null) {
        qv = new QuestionView (nContext, nQuestion[position], nDetail[position], nExpanded[position]);
    } else {
        qv = (QuestionView)convertView;
        qv.setName(nQuestion[position]);
        qv.setDetail(nDetail[position]);
        qv.setExpanded(nExpanded[position]);
    }        
    return qv;
}
```

But how do I call the method? If I have no old view and the parent isn't `LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT`

My onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   // Use our own list adapter
   setListAdapter(new QuestionsListAdapter(this));
}
```

So how do I call the getView method, because if I run the code it isn't drawing. 
Somthing like this?

```
QuestionsListAdapter.getView( 0,  convertView,  parent);
```

Comment: You did not pass your data to the adapter, check http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

Comment: you don't call it, it is called internally by the listview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not have to call the method. If you override the method in a customAdapter, it is called automatically each time the `Adapter` gets data from your data source and puts it in a `View` that represents an item in your `ListView`.